# electron free mean path understanding

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electrons, scattering, scattering-cross-section

I am having difficulties to grasp the idea that the probability a particle is absorbed between $x$ and $x + dx$ is given by

$$dP(x) = \frac{I(x) - I(x+dx)}{I_0} = \frac{1}{l} e^{-\frac{x}{l}}dx$$

with $$I(x) = I_{0}e^{-\frac{x}{l}} $$

can someone help me to understand this?

I also tried to understand it mathematically and got different result

$$dP(x) ={} \frac{I(x) - I(x+dx)}{I_0} = e^{-\frac{x}{l}} (1 - e^{-\frac{dx}{l}})$$

is there any assumption that I did not include?

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path

Comment: If you expand your results up to first order in $dx$, you will get the same answer. I think it's because $dx$ is supposed to be so small that higher order terms can be neglected.

Comment: i got the answer. will put them here this weekend.